# JQuery - TypeError: $(...).tableToJSON is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola amigos tengo una tabla que renderizo con js y una vez la tengo necesito hacer otro proceso y los datos de esa tabla convertirlos en un json, para eventualmente mandarlos por un form, encontré esta librería que pretende ayudarme https://www.github.developerdan.com/table-to-json/ y este ejemplito que es de donde me estoy guiando http://jsfiddle.net/Crw2C/173/
bueno ya descargué la librería y la incluí, con la terminal veo que estoy recibiendo  `jquery.tabletojson.min.js` sin problemas, pero mi error persiste

> TypeError: $(...).tableToJSON is not a function
>   , aquí les dejo lo que estoy haciendo

Scripts que me pidieron
Los scripts los agrego en mi footer

```
 <script src="~/js/jquery.tabletojson.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/js/calculadoradeprestamos.js"></script>

                <input type="button" name="name" value="Solicitar cotización" onclick="operar()" id="submit_btn" />



                <br />

                <div id="error" class="panel panel-danger">
                    <div class="panel-heading" id="errorMsn"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 ">
                <div class=" top2 invisible" id="Tpagos">


                    <table class="table table-hover" id="Tablepagos">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Núm.Pago</th>
                                <th>Fecha</th>
                                <th>Cantidad</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="Tbodypagos"></tbody>
                    </table>


                </div>


            </div>
```

```js
 // esto es operar()
if (todobienytranquilamente) { console.log('yeah')}
//esto es lo que me interesa 
else {

  var prestamo = amount * (1 + (.20));
  var pagolapso = prestamo / numpagos;

  var datecreated = new Date();
  var dd = datecreated.getDay().toString();
  var mm = datecreated.getMonth().toString();
  var yyyy = datecreated.getFullYear().toString();
  var hrs = datecreated.getHours().toString();
  var min = datecreated.getUTCMinutes().toString();


  var dat = dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy + " " + hrs + ":" + min;
  document.getElementById("headMsn").
  innerHTML = "<div align='center'><h2>Tabla de pagos</h2></div>";
  $('#Tpagos').removeClass('invisible');
  // días de pago

  var numpInt = parseInt(numpagos);
  let date = new Date();

  let day = date.getDate();
  let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  let year = date.getFullYear();

  for (let i = 1; i <= numpInt; i++) {
    Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
      var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
      return date;
    }
    let d = new Date(day, month, year);
    let adddays = lapsoreal * i;
    let dnew = d.addDays(adddays);

    // alert(i)
    document.getElementById("Tbodypagos").innerHTML += `
                            <tr>
                                <td> ${ i } </td>
                                <td> ${ dnew } </td>
                                <td> ${ pagolapso } </td>
                            </tr>
                        `;


    document.getElementById("errorMsn").
    innerHTML = "<br/><label>Especificaciones</label><br>" +
      "lapso: cada " + lapsoreal + " días - $" + pagolapso +
      " / " + " número de pagos : " + numpagos +
      " / total a pagar: " + prestamo + " fecha de solicitud : " +
      datecreated + "<br/>" +
      "" + "<br/>" +
      "<section id='call - to - action' class='wow fadeIn'>" +
      "<h5>¿Te gustaría recibir esta información?</h5>" +
      "<input type = 'maill' placeholder = 'tumail@ejemplo.com' name = 'mail' class='form-control top5' required />" +
      "<input type = 'button' name = 'name' id='tabletojson' value = 'Enviar'  class='pull-right top5 cta-btn'/>" +
      "</section>";


    $("#submit_btn").prop('disabled', true);


  }
  
  //aquí está mi error, les dejo lo demás solo para que tengan contexto de donde está saliendo todo
  $('#tabletojson').click(function() {
    var table = $('#Tablepagos').tableToJSON();
    alert(JSON.stringify(table));
  });

  //$('#calculoform').addClass('d-none');//

}
```

Comment: Añade la parte donde estás añadiendo los scripts al html

Comment: Saludos debes agregar tu HTML de como incluyes las librerias que mencionas, dado que da la impresión que estas llamando primero a la libreria "tableToJSON" antes de estar definida ó cargada esta por lo cual ayudaria mucho si agregas en que orden estas cargando tus librerias y tu codigo JavaScript

Comment: @DiegoAvila listo todo cual lo tengo y donde lo estoy llamando

Comment: el archivo " calculadoradeprestamos.js " es donde estas colocando tu código JavaScript e invocando tableToJSON ?

Comment: La referencia al `jquery.tabletojson.min.js` esta mala , o no la agregaste bien , si quitas la referencia en el ejemplo de **JSFiddle**  te darás cuenta que saca tu mismo error (http://jsfiddle.net/Crw2C/173/), mira este ejemplo abre la consola en el navegador y da click al botón te muestra el mismo error, revisa tu librería

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO hola, en mi firefox me dice que RECIBE el https://localhost:5001/js/jquery.tabletojson.min.js 304 osea que si llega, @D

Comment: @DiegoAvila si diego así es

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim Muéstrame el archivo del `tabletojson` porfa, Seguro tienes bien la referencia?  dale `f12` y le dices Ver codigo fuente de la pagina y le das click al link del `tabletojson`  a ver que te saca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa este **snippet** lo que hice fue pegar el código de la pagina del `tableToJSON` y funciono

```js
$('#run').click(function() {
  var table = $('#Tablepagos').tableToJSON();
  alert(JSON.stringify(table));
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<script>
/* Este fue el código que pegue de la pagina*/
$( document ).ready(function() {
!function(a){"use strict";a.fn.tableToJSON=function(b){var c={ignoreColumns:[],onlyColumns:null,ignoreHiddenRows:!0,ignoreEmptyRows:!1,headings:null,allowHTML:!1,includeRowId:!1,textDataOverride:"data-override",textExtractor:null};b=a.extend(c,b);var d=function(a){return void 0!==a&&null!==a},e=function(c){return d(b.onlyColumns)?-1===a.inArray(c,b.onlyColumns):-1!==a.inArray(c,b.ignoreColumns)},f=function(b,c){var e={},f=0;return a.each(c,function(a,c){f<b.length&&d(c)&&(e[b[f]]=c,f++)}),e},g=function(c,d,e){var f=a(d),g=b.textExtractor,h=f.attr(b.textDataOverride);return null===g||e?a.trim(h||(b.allowHTML?f.html():d.textContent||f.text())||""):a.isFunction(g)?a.trim(h||g(c,f)):"object"==typeof g&&a.isFunction(g[c])?a.trim(h||g[c](c,f)):a.trim(h||(b.allowHTML?f.html():d.textContent||f.text())||"")},h=function(c,d){var e=[],f=b.includeRowId,h="boolean"==typeof f?f:"string"==typeof f?!0:!1,i="string"==typeof f==!0?f:"rowId";return h&&"undefined"==typeof a(c).attr("id")&&e.push(i),a(c).children("td,th").each(function(a,b){e.push(g(a,b,d))}),e},i=function(a){var c=a.find("tr:first").first();return d(b.headings)?b.headings:h(c,!0)},j=function(c,h){var i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p=[],q=0,r=[];return c.children("tbody,*").children("tr").each(function(c,e){if(c>0||d(b.headings)){var f=b.includeRowId,h="boolean"==typeof f?f:"string"==typeof f?!0:!1;n=a(e);var r=n.find("td").length===n.find("td:empty").length?!0:!1;!n.is(":visible")&&b.ignoreHiddenRows||r&&b.ignoreEmptyRows||n.data("ignore")&&"false"!==n.data("ignore")||(q=0,p[c]||(p[c]=[]),h&&(q+=1,"undefined"!=typeof n.attr("id")?p[c].push(n.attr("id")):p[c].push("")),n.children().each(function(){for(o=a(this);p[c][q];)q++;if(o.filter("[rowspan]").length)for(k=parseInt(o.attr("rowspan"),10)-1,m=g(q,o),i=1;k>=i;i++)p[c+i]||(p[c+i]=[]),p[c+i][q]=m;if(o.filter("[colspan]").length)for(k=parseInt(o.attr("colspan"),10)-1,m=g(q,o),i=1;k>=i;i++)if(o.filter("[rowspan]").length)for(l=parseInt(o.attr("rowspan"),10),j=0;l>j;j++)p[c+j][q+i]=m;else p[c][q+i]=m;m=p[c][q]||g(q,o),d(m)&&(p[c][q]=m),q++}))}}),a.each(p,function(c,g){if(d(g)){var i=d(b.onlyColumns)||b.ignoreColumns.length?a.grep(g,function(a,b){return!e(b)}):g,j=d(b.headings)?h:a.grep(h,function(a,b){return!e(b)});m=f(j,i),r[r.length]=m}}),r},k=i(this);return j(this,k)}}(jQuery);
});
</script>



<button id="run" class="btn btn-primary">Convert!</button>

<div class="col-lg-6 ">
  <div class=" top2 invisible" id="Tpagos">
    <table id='Tablepagos'>
      <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>Núm.Pago</th>
             <th>Fecha</th>
             <th>Cantidad</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Jill</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
          <td>50</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: funcionó bastante bien y veo que estas usando ecmascript pordrías explicar un poco qué pasó?

Comment: Solo supuse que si no estaba definido era por dos razones, por que al presentarse ese error aparece siempre que no este la librería definida , valide que no estuviera bien el nombre `.tableToJSON();` pero lo estaba, lo otro era que no estuviera bien la referencia, entonces, solo entre al `JSFiddel` que pusiste y hice click en la referencia del `tableJson` copie el código y lo inicialice en Jquery , al probar funciono, lo que me quiso decir que la referencia estaba mal o copiaste mal el código en tu archivo.